# Detect which link was clicked with javascript that got user to specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Been searching on the web for a solution, but couldn't find anything, so maybe it's not possible, although I hope it still is.

What Im trying to do is detect the button (class or id) that was clicked when being redirected to another page on my site.

What I have is a portfolio page that contains a large amount of divs with different classes, so when someone clicks on a specific button on the homepage and gets redirected to the portfolio page, is it possible to detect on the portfolio page how the visitor got directed from. So detect which button got clicked.

no idea how to approach this, something maybe with if previous window.location last action find class or id.

Hopefully my question makes sense and someone can give me an idea if even possible.

I imagine it would rather be possible to do with php, but unfortunately server side languages are not an option in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it without either modifying the links (adding a query string or hash), or having code on the source pages (where the links are).

The former is pretty obvious: Just add a query string or hash (I'd use a hash) that identifies where the click came from, and look for the hash on the portfolio page. E.g., links:

```
<a href="portfolio#foo">Portfolio</a>
<a href="portfolio#bar">Portfolio</a>
```

and in the portfolio page:

```
var from = location.hash;
```

If you don't want to do that, and you can put code on those pages, it's easy: Add a click handler that sets information about the link in `sessionStorage` ([very well-supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) on modern browsers), and look for it in `sessionStorage` when you get to the portfolio page.

E.g.,:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e) {
    // Maybe check the link is going to portfolio, or refine the selector above
    sessionStorage.setItem("linkFrom", this.className);
});
```

and then in the portfolio page:

```
var from = sessionstorage.getItem("linkFrom");
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the extended answer and the option that can be used to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Examples of methods you can use

1. add the information in the originating url - use location.search or location.hash depending on your choice of ? or #
2. Set a cookie (or use session/localStorage in modern browsers) in originating page and read it in the target page
3. Interrogate document.referrer (not always set)

Comment: Setting cookie is a good option since it'll be passed to server(and back) with each request/response cycle! (unless you delete it)

Comment: Thanks for providing the available options for my issue and more then happy to hear it is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.localStorage to save the last id of the clicked element.

```
localStorage.setItem('last_clicked_id', id);
```

And then read it in the next page:

```
localStorage.last_clicked_id
```

Before running you should check for localStorage support:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    //localStorage code
} else {
    //no localStorage support
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how it works: the recent page or url is set on the URL parameters like a GET server request, but instead the client will receive it and parse it not the server. the recent page or url is on the "fromurl" parameter. on every page put this in (it's a javascript code):

```
function getURIparams(s) {
loc = window.location.href;
loc = loc.substring((loc.indexOf("?")+1));
loc = loc.split("&");
for (l = 0; l < loc.length; l++) {
    lcc = loc[l].split("=");
    if (lcc[0] == s) {
        return lcc[1];
        break;
    }
}
}
```

next on every anchor link put this in href:

```
<a href="/anotherpage.html?fromurl=/[current_page_the_user_is_viewing].html">The Link to another page</a>
```

after that, on every page execute this javascript:

```
from_url = getURIparams("fromurl");
```

the "from_url" variable will be the string variable of where the user clicked before it comes to that page.

if you are to lazy to put all those anchor one by one like this, do this work around but you need jquery for this. you dont need to put the parameter on the links for it to know where it comes from it will be automatically added by jquery.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     window.location.href =  e.target.href + "?fromurl=" + window.location.pathname;
});
```